# Any recommendation/suggestion on best practice to develop app using PhoneGap for Android or iOS?

Tags: webkit, cordova, mobile-application

Also, is there a way to test those webapp in a webkit based browser such as chrome (with phonegap plug-in maybe) on a PC first before compiling it to test on a device or emulator?

The key reason is that  trouble shooting mal-formed html, javascript code is very difficult on a device or emulator.  You can not view the js console to see all error. The Weinre is great, but it can not spits out the error browser complains when initially loading the page.

It will be great if we can validate the html, js, css  app first before diving deeper into testing on Android device. i.e.  a way to weed out some simple problems before getting into more complicated deeper problems.

Any experience/suggestions/ideas/pointers are greatly appreciated.

Paul> Seems promising. Will try and report back. It seems knowledgeable in phoneGap mob dev.  What are the key steps would you go through to dev  a  phoneGap mob web-app?

Answer (score 1):

[Ripple](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/about) is a Chrome plug-in that includes a PhoneGap mode.

For JavaScript static validation, the PhoneGap Android Eclipse AppLaud plug-in includes a [JSLint](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/announce-1/mds12released-nowwithjslintjshint) mode.

Comment: >  Ripple seems to be crash prone on my ubuntu +chrome. even I launched from cmd line. /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome  --enable-plugins  --allow-file-access-from-files      It is in the right direction though, but not quite there yet. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use Safari.  In your Safari (on Mac) go to Settings (on PC) goto preferences -> Advanced -> check on "Show Develop in Menu bar".

Now you'll find in the Menu "Develop" "User Agent". There you can change the UserAgent identification, that will be send to the server.  You can then change it to iPhone.

This way you can at least test it for iOS.

Hope that helps somewhat.